# Override Woocommerce Elements

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having the hardest time trying to modify the woocommerce layout for the storefont template. My directory is:

1. Location for woocommerce plugin: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates`
2. I copy everything in the templates folder above into: `wp-content/themes/storefront_child/woocommerce/`
3. Modify any file inside the woocommerce folder above such as writing
   *OMG* anywhere on the page.
4. Nothing shows in my page.

I am a rookie in WordPress and I have no idea how to modify the files for a plugin/template. I have not activated my child template either (is that required?). When I duplicate the woocommerce files and try to install them, it says the template is missing.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question as you've already sorted it but, here's a bit of advice, only copy the template files you are editing in your woocommerce folder in your theme. There's no point in overriding a template file with the exact same template file

Answer (score 2):

open up `functions.php`
then copy below code on there:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

and then check the result

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it after much research. Most sites neglect to mention that what actually "activates" the child theme is the comment in the CSS. So the child theme MUST include the CSS with the information that links it to the parent child. In my case:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   storefront-child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/
 Description:  StoreFront
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     storefront
 Version:      1.3.1
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your child theme has not configured properly. You please double check below points.

1. You activated Child Theme (Not the parent)
2. Your child theme has a style.css file with below code

   ```
   /*
   Theme Name:   My Child Theme
   Description:  A Twenty Thirteen child theme 
   Author:       My author
   Template:     twentythirteen
   Version:      1.0.0
   */
   ```
3. You properly Enqueued the Styles and Scripts.

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_add_stylesheet' );
   function my_theme_add_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
   }
   ```